Invalid Qualifier - For two sets of Boolean Conditions
Hi I'm new to Excel VBA trying to tell the VBA to autocalculate should my autocalculate checkbox be selected.
And if the autocalculate checkbox is selected, to check if the RectanglePerp checkbox is selected. If RectanglePerp is selected then to calculate using first formula else second formula. And if autocalculate is not selected to manual key in the value. Not sure what Im doing wrong here.
Updated vba:
 If chkAutoCal.Value = True Then
    If chkRectanglePerp.Value = True Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = 2 * ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Value + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value + (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value - 1) * ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = 2 * ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10).Value + ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value + (ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value - 1) * ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value
    End If
 Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = txtPileCapBreath.Value
 End If
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
 ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).NumberFormat = Range("N4").NumberFormat

Previous vba:
 Dim chkAutoCal As Boolean
 Dim chkRectanglePerp As Boolean
 
 If chkAutoCal.Value = True Then
     If chkRectanglePerp = True Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = txtEndDist.Value + txtPileDiameter.Value + (txtRowNo.Value - 1) * ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value + txtEndDist.Value
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = txtEdgeDist.Value + txtPileDiamter.Value + ((txtPileNo.Value / txtRowNo.Value) - 1) * ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value + txtEdgeDist.Value
    End If
 Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).Value = txtPileCapBreath.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 11).NumberFormat = Range("N4").NumberFormat


End If is missing at the end.

Hi @taller, thanks for pointing it out, I've included the End If but I'm still getting an invalid qualifier error.

Remove two Dim lines. I guess both chkAutoCal and chkRectanglePerp are controls in your file. Dim clauses claim them as a varible.  The invalid qualifier error is on chkAutoCal.Value . That is, Boolean varible doesn't have Value property.

Hi @taller, thanks. I've updated it and the nested condition is working. Only issue i'm having at the moment is that i get an object error when i tried to key in a manual value for the parent 'else' condition

If txtPileCapBreath is not on the active sheet, you will get error 424. Pls qualify all controls with the sheet object. eg. Sheets("YourSheetName").txtPileCapBreath.Value

Summary of comments:

Remove the two Dim lines. Both chkAutoCal and chkRectanglePerp are controls in your file. The Dim statements declare them as variables, causing the invalid qualifier error on chkAutoCal.Value. A Boolean variable does not have a Value property.

If txtPileCapBreath is NOT on the active sheet, you will get error 424. Please qualify all controls with the sheet object. eg. Sheets("YourSheetName").txtPileCapBreath.Value.


